# OctoberCMS Front end file download

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have written a component to save some data and a file on the front end then email the data collected to the customer, I want to include a download link to the file which was uploaded but I am having no luck.
So code looks like this:

```
public function onAddTask() {
        //Assign variables to be used in email
            $emailTaskVars = [
                'client_name' => Input::get('client_name'),
                'client_email' => Input::get('client_email'),
                'emergency_contact' => Input::get('emergency_contact'),
                'task_query' => Input::get('task_query'),
                'rotation' => Input::get('rotation'),
                'qty_across' => Input::get('qty_across'),
                'qty_around' => Input::get('qty_around'),
                'teeth_qty' => Input::get('teeth_qty'),
                'imaging' => Input::get('imaging'),
                'stepped_query' => Input::get('stepped_query'),
                'customer' => $this->loadCompany(),
                'project_name' => Input::get('project_name'),
                'file' => $this->file()
            ];
        //Send email
        Mail::send('acme.email::mail.task', $emailTaskVars, function($message) {
            $message->to([Input::get('client_email') => 'User Email'], [$this->technicalEmail() => 'Technical Email'], 'Acme Email');
            $message->subject('New Task');
        });
        //Save to the database
        $task = new Task();
        $task->client_name = Input::get('client_name');
        $task->client_email = Input::get('client_email');
        $task->emergency_contact = Input::get('emergency_contact');
        $task->task_query = Input::get('task_query');
        $task->stepped_query = Input::get('stepped_query');
        $task->customer = $this->loadCompany();
        $task->project_name = Input::get('project_name');
        $task->file = Input::file('fileuploader');
        $task->slug = Input::file('slug');
        $task->save();
        Flash::success('Task has been submitted!');
        return Redirect::to('/home');
    }
}
```

Then I have a function to get the file path, this is where it breaks:

```
protected function file() {
    $file = $task->file()->first();
    echo $file->getPath();
}
```

in my email I am calling the name like this:

```
File : {{ file }}
```

Comment: Looks like `$task` is out of scope. Please post the error you are getting it help immensely. however, if I'm correct the error you are getting is `Call to a member function first() on null`. And if that is the case (i'm like 90% sure), then you need to rework your logic a bit and find an appropriate place to set `$task`

Comment: Please see this demonstration to understand about scopes: https://3v4l.org/umlnN

Comment: @WillParky93 Thanks for your help, the error is "Undefined variable: item" I got this from another forum, I have to be honest I am very lost with this as I am fairly new to backend dev

Comment: In the code you posted I cannot seem to find a call to `item`. Undefined variable notice will not break your code usually, PHP will still execute. I advise you spend some time understanding about classes. However, don't be put off as this stuff isn't usualy for novice programmers. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Also, it's better practice to `return` rather than `echo` inside a function such as `protected function file() {`

Comment: sorry the error was Undefined variable: task. I am reading up and trying to find a solution but no luck thus far

Comment: @WillParky93 I have changed the file function to this:

`public function getImageAttribute() {
        $image = Task::find($this->id);
        return $image->file->getPath();
    }`

But still no luck, this return an exception: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Could you please include the full class in the OP please

Comment: @WillParky93 http://pastiebin.com/embed/5a0aeb2c4b47e

Comment: https://pastiebin.com/5a0aeb2c4b47e Look at line 85. I'm unfamiliar with this class and laravel in general. But this would be how you would correctly set those values. Hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158963/discussion-between-gareth-and-willparky93).

Comment: @WillParky93 now I get this error:
`Call to a member function first() on null`

Comment: Sorry Gareth I don't have the ability to chat in the rooms. My boss would kill me! On that script I sent you;  try removing the `first()` from `$file = $this->taskFile->first();` and then `var_dump($file)` within that function. As I said previously; I'm not familiar with the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you are saving that file to tasks so you know id of task..

now we assume that you are only attaching one file to task and you want user to download that in frontend.

so prepare link like that it will point to front-end page "download" which will accept id as task id.

`// ex : http://localhost/task-file-download.htm?id=<<task_id>>`

now get this id from params in page then fetch that task then get that file object which is attached to it.

first check file object with

```
dd($file);
```

if its collection then user **first()** to get first file and if its simply single **File**

```
echo $file->output();
```

It will add appropriate headers and user can download files.

see october-cms docs

https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments#file-attachments

It described clearly how to let user download file.

If more query please add comment.